# salt stack error when trying to run job: Failed to authenticate, is this user permitted to execute

Tags: salt-stack

Getting the following error when running any salt job:

> [ERROR   ] Salt request timed out. If this error persists, worker_threads may need to be increased.
>   Failed to authenticate, is this user permitted to execute commands?

Seeing the error after waiting many minutes.  Restarting salt didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I forgot to look in the /var/log/salt/master log file which had the answer in it...

> IOError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
>   2016-09-27 16:18:48,266 [salt.master                                 ][ERROR   ] Exception [Errno 28] No space left on device occurred in file server update

So, I had simply run out of disk space.